# Thread freezes on initialising an object in scala referencing the object being initialised

Tags: multithreading, scala, object, initialization

I struggled with a specific problem with java Threads and initialisation of an object in scala. In my original code a Thread freezes. I finally found a solution for my problem. But I do not understand why this works.

I have rewritten the problem into the following code. Running this, the code stops at the first line in the Thread that references to a variable of the object being initialised. If the reference is through the self variable which points to this initialising object, it executes fine.

```
object Alpha {
    var r = "A"
    r = "B"
    System.out.println("Not threaded: r = " + r)
    val thread = 
        {
            val self = this

            new Thread(
                new Runnable 
                {
                    def run() =
                        {
                            System.out.println("    Started.")
                            System.out.println("    Threaded self.r = " + self.r)
                            self.r = "C"
                            System.out.println("    Threaded self.r = " + self.r)

                            // At the following line the thread freezes!
                            System.out.println("    Threaded r = " + r) 
                            r = "D"
                            System.out.println("    Threaded r = " + r)
                        }
                })
        }
    thread.start
    thread.join
}
```

Calling Alpha will result in the following output before execution is frozen.

```
Not threaded: r = B
    Started.
    Threaded self.r = B
    Threaded self.r = C
```

I would understand if referencing to object variables during initialisation is prohibited at all times. But now it looks a bit randomly.

Comment: If I compile and run it with 2.12.4, it runs through and prints `Not threaded: r = B
    Started.
    Threaded self.r = B
    Threaded self.r = C
    Threaded r = C
    Threaded r = D` I've added a `println(Alpha)` to force the instantiation.

Comment: I've tried it with:

Comment: I've tried it with: Scala 2.12.2 and 2.12.3 with Java RTE 1.8.0_144. After your comment updated to Scala 2.12.5and Java RTE 1.8.0.162. I run it in the Scala Interpreter (Scala.exe) and instantiate by calling Alpha instead of a println. Unfortunately this still freezes the execution. @Andrey. Could you please inform me on the Java RTE you use? It seems to run like I'd expect with your settings. I'd love it to have this working on my system, as I feel that I have a non elegant bugfix solution.

Comment: I compiled it as script with `scalac -version` 2.12.4 and run it on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode). It could be that it actually depends on the scarcity/abundance of available threads, I'm running it on a very lightweight hardware setup. It might be that it's just not deterministic. Why exactly do you want to pass a reference of a not completely initialized singleton object to another thread anyway...

Comment: E.g. try running it on [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/): it also runs without problems to end there. That's probably again because it uses at most one core to execute your code...

Comment: Now I've got it working in the Scala Interpreter. If I wrap the code in a function liek def test() = {....} and call the function, it works. As I not specifically need the Singelon, but on each call a new one may be created, this works for me. But still.... Why does this not work if I define Alpha as a Singleton in a Package?